# ACF Conditional in Script-tag / variation.php - is it possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields

I have a bit of a conundrum in regards to conditional logic within ACF/WP. I have set up a checkbox, that when clicked should show the data inside. Since this is happening inside variation.php I seem to have issues getting it to work. My initial thought is, that because it is inside a  tag, it might cause issues? Here is the (nonworking) code:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>
    <?php if( get_field('sla_tags_til_pa_variant') ): ?>
    <p class="variation-p">Se alle andre smykker i </p><a class="variation-a" href="{{{ data.variation.guld_solv_links_til_tags }}}">{{{ data.variation.guld_solv_tags }}}</a> <a class="variation-a" href="{{{ data.variation.farver_links_til_tags }}}">{{{ data.variation.farver_tags }}}</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

When the checkbox is checked nothing appears. Any clue what is wrong, or if it is impossible to do conditional logic via PHP inside the script tag?

Comment: As long as this is in a context where PHP will get interpreted, it doesn't matter whether you place this into a `script` element - or any other element, for that matter.

Comment: Strange - I suppose it should work then. I wonder if the variation aspect has something to do with it

Comment: Where did you actually store the ACF value, under what post id? You might need to explicitly specify the post id via the second parameter of `get_field`, if you are not in the context of the post id this was actually stored under.

Comment: By store, you mean the location rules? They are a bit weird set up to be able to apply them on a product variation, there might be some mismatch somewhere in that process

Comment: I mean which post ID the value you stored, is actually associated with. So this would be the individual product variation then in this case? And what is the context of the above code, where is that located? If this is not in a location where the current post would be the variation, you will have to supply the variation ID in the `get_field` call.

Comment: Must be yeah - it's a part of WooCommerce handling product variations variation.php. If I insert only this part (the data.variation is also connected to ACF fields) I can change between items within the selectbox, and it is shown on the front-end: <p class="variation-p">Se alle andre smykker i </p><a class="variation-a" href="{{{ data.variation.guld_solv_links_til_tags }}}">{{{ data.variation.guld_solv_tags }}}</a> <a class="variation-a" href="{{{ data.variation.farver_links_til_tags }}}">{{{ data.variation.farver_tags }}}</a>

But fwhen trying to wrap it in the conditional produces nothing

Comment: If you were to add the ID for the variation product, how would you grab it dynamically and parse it?

Comment: I can't tell if you are actually in a PHP context there or not - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/override-variation-php-template/ rather suggest, that might not be the case. You might have to do this using underscore templating syntax instead. (Assuming that your ACF value is already contained in `data.variation`, if not I wouldn't know how to get it in a non-PHP context.)

Comment: Hmm, yeah it might just be outside the scope of PHP. A bit more difficult than I imagined, this problem. Thanks for taking a look at it anyways, though!

Comment: I managed to solve it, by inserting it as a classname in a div: <div class="variation-container {{{ data.variation.sla_tags_til_pa_variant }}}"> setting the display to block when the checkbox is checked. Not a perfect solution, not pretty, but it works